# Clicking on CEdit and CSpinButton causes losing capture in MFC dialog

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a dialog box which i use for picking colors. It consists of a buttons that represent colors and an edit control with buddy spin button.
When i create the dialog i call `SetCapture()` in order to get the clicks and whenever they are outside of the dialog it should closes.

Everything works fine until i click on a edit control or on it's buddy. After that `CMyDialog::OnLButtonDown()` will not be called, because i suppose that the capture is lost.

I tried calling `SetCapture()` in `ON_EN_CHANGE` message handler but it does not solve the problem.

My qestion is: 
Where should i call `SetCapture()` in order to close the dialog when i have already clicked on the edit control or it's spin button?

Comment: Why are you calling SetCapture in first place ? It's not needed.

Comment: Because the dialog is called with DoModal and it is needed to be closed if the user clicks outside of it's window.

Comment: I'm not sure if this the right method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that i have taken is not right at all. Turns out that ON_WM_NCACTIVATE message should be handled and the dialog should be closed if

```
CDialog::OnNcActivate( bActive ) returns false.

the function looks like this :

BOOL CMyDialog::OnNcActivate( BOOL bActive )
{
    BOOL bResult = CDialog::OnNcActivate( bActive );

    if( !bActive )
    {
        PostMessage( WM_CLOSE );
    }

    return bResult;
}
```